# Sage Pay provides mobile SDK to integrate in mobile app?

Tags: mobile, sdk, opayo

I can't find any information about Sage Pay's mobile SDK so that i can integrate it into my mobile app.
My Customers ask me about this.
Anybody has info? Please let me know. Many thanks!

Comment: I don't think there is an SDK available but the you can integrate with the APIs already available.
Take into account PCI compliance if you for example let the customer enter the cc details on your app.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the new integration method at: https://test.sagepay.com/documentation - I've used this to create an Android integration, but as Pablo says, you will need to take into account the PCI implications